# AngularJS - ngShow/ngSwitch/ngIf - Two elements flicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a two elements that are rendered inside an **ng-repeat**, when I click a button that does a toggle, for a brief second both elements get shown.

I have tried various things, ngIf, ngShow, ngSwitch and ngCloak and nothing seems to work.

Here is a code sample:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in view.myModel.items">
        <div class="row">
            <a ng-hide="item.link" class="btn ng-cloak"
               ng-click="view.getLink($index)">Get Link</a>

            <a ng-show="item.link" class="btn ng-cloak"
               data-ng-href="{{item.link}}" download>Download</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

So here is the problem, on load I only see the 'Get Link' button which is fine.

As soon as I click it, it makes a http call and sets the 'items.link' value, which is where the problem happens. At that moment **both** buttons are shown together.

Then correctly just the download button shows.

Here is the http call if your interested:

```
/**
 * Get a link
 */
function getLink(idx) {
    Linker
        .getLink(idx)
        .then(onGotLink);

    function onGotLink(link) {
        myModel.items[idx].link = link.url;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a third state that shows a brief "loading" message. It's flickering because of the lag between request and response from the server.

Comment: OP is using promises and only after the http promise resolves, the `myModel.items[idx].link` is set. I don't see how the server response time would affect this.\

Comment: Could it be the animation classes (e.g. `ng-hide-animate`) that is causing both buttons to be temporarily shown? Use a dom-modification break-point to see the state of the dom/scope when both buttons are shown.

Comment: Please add more code snippet because it is not possible that both the elements get visible at the same time. Your code must be altering the value of `item.link` somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Bingo, your right, it is ng-animate causing issues. You should make an answer. Turning it off fixes the flicker.

Comment: `ng-animate` is a creature of hell. I can't count the problems it has caused, and it's not even easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So credit to user1620220 who pointed it out. The issue is ng-animate is running that is causing the ng-hide-animate to trigger causing that slight flicker.

You can turn off ng-animate, or use CSS to turn of 'transition' if you only want to partially disable it is.